# Could DLL injection be used to break out of a sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, dll-injection

For instance Sandboxie on Windows. Could a sandboxed program use DLL injection to migrate its execution to another process outside the sandbox?

Comment: Different sandbox technologies work differently. Are you asking about Sandboxie specifically? If so, please make that clearer. As written, it seems that Sandboxie is just an example rather than the focus of the question. (Also, this isn't yet a programming question.)

Answer (score 0):

No, a program running in Sandboxie can't interact with other processes that is the purpose of a sandbox.  To do so would require a sandbox escape vulnerability